# Making a row highlighted when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'd like to add functionality to my html page to highlight (change the row color to #DFDFDF) when selected.

If another row is selected then, then return the row color to its initial color and color the newly selected row.

Note that when the top header is clicked, id like to exempt that from ever changing color.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q42L2/

Much thanks and appreciation for all of your help

```
<div id="results" class="scrollingdatagrid">

  <table id="mstrTable" cellspacing="0">
     <thead>
      <tr> 
        <th>File Number</th>
        <th>Date1</th>
        <th>Date2</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Num.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Lockdown</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>

        <td>09/15/2002</td>

        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WROC</td>

        <td>10/11/2002</td>

        <td>10/11/2002</td>

        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WPPP</td>
        <td>09/16/2002</td>
        <td>09/16/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>

        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WRRR</td>
        <td>09/06/2002</td>
        <td>09/06/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>5</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTTT</td>
        <td>09/21/2002</td>
        <td>09/21/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>W000</td>
        <td>11/11/2002</td>
        <td>11/11/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>

        <td>10/01/2002</td>

        <td>10/01/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>

        <td>10/18/2002</td>

        <td>10/18/2002</td>

        <td>Lockdown</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>10/18/2002</td>
        <td>10/18/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>

        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>
        <td>10/19/2002</td>
        <td>10/19/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WROC</td>
        <td>07/18/2002</td>
        <td>07/18/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WPPP</td>
        <td>10/28/2002</td>
        <td>10/28/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WRRR</td>

        <td>10/28/2002</td>

        <td>10/28/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTTT</td>

        <td>10/08/2002</td>

        <td>10/08/2002</td>

        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WIL0</td>
        <td>10/18/2001</td>
        <td>10/18/2001</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>

        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>
        <td>04/18/2002</td>
        <td>04/18/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>
        <td>10/05/2001</td>
        <td>10/05/2001</td>
        <td>Lockdown</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>10/18/2002</td>
        <td>10/18/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>

        <td>10/19/2002</td>

        <td>10/19/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WROC</td>

        <td>12/18/2002</td>

        <td>12/18/2002</td>

        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WPPP</td>
        <td>12/28/2002</td>
        <td>12/28/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>

        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WRRR</td>
        <td>12/20/2002</td>
        <td>12/20/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>5</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTTT</td>
        <td>12/11/2002</td>
        <td>12/11/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>W0VB</td>
        <td>01/18/2003</td>
        <td>01/18/2003</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>17</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>

        <td>12/17/2002</td>

        <td>12/17/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>

        <td>12/16/2002</td>

        <td>12/16/2002</td>

        <td>Lockdown</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WFAA</td>
        <td>12/18/2002</td>
        <td>12/18/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>

        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>
        <td>12/18/2002</td>
        <td>12/18/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WROC</td>
        <td>12/19/2002</td>
        <td>12/19/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WPPP</td>
        <td>12/06/2002</td>
        <td>12/06/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WRRR</td>

        <td>12/28/2002</td>

        <td>12/28/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTTT</td>

        <td>12/30/2002</td>

        <td>12/30/2002</td>

        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>UMBA</td>
        <td>12/26/2002</td>
        <td>12/26/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>

        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>
        <td>12/18/2002</td>
        <td>12/18/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>
        <td>12/29/2002</td>
        <td>12/29/2002</td>
        <td>Lockdown</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WFFF</td>
        <td>12/22/2002</td>
        <td>12/22/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>

        <td>12/18/2001</td>

        <td>12/18/2001</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WROC</td>

        <td>11/19/2001</td>

        <td>11/19/2001</td>

        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WPPP</td>
        <td>11/20/2001</td>
        <td>11/20/2001</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>

        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WRRR</td>
        <td>10/19/2001</td>
        <td>10/19/2001</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>5</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTTT</td>
        <td>11/29/2001</td>
        <td>11/29/2001</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>KPLT</td>
        <td>11/19/2001</td>
        <td>11/19/2001</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>

        <td>11/19/2001</td>

        <td>11/19/2001</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KBRE</td>

        <td>11/19/2001</td>

        <td>11/19/2001</td>

        <td>Lockdown</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>11/19/2001</td>
        <td>11/19/2001</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>

        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>
        <td>02/19/2003</td>
        <td>02/19/2003</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WROC</td>
        <td>02/17/2003</td>
        <td>02/17/2003</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WPPP</td>
        <td>02/16/2003</td>
        <td>02/16/2003</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WRRR</td>

        <td>02/29/2003</td>

        <td>02/29/2003</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTTT</td>

        <td>03/19/2003</td>

        <td>03/19/2003</td>

        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KLTR</td>
        <td>02/10/2003</td>
        <td>02/10/2003</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>

        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>
        <td>04/05/2003</td>
        <td>04/05/2003</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>16</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>
        <td>02/19/2003</td>
        <td>02/19/2003</td>
        <td>Lockdown</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>02/16/2003</td>
        <td>02/16/2003</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>

        <td>02/13/2003</td>

        <td>02/13/2003</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WROC</td>

        <td>02/14/2003</td>

        <td>02/14/2003</td>

        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WPPP</td>
        <td>03/19/2003</td>
        <td>03/19/2003</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>

        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WRRR</td>
        <td>02/19/2002</td>
        <td>02/19/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>5</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTTT</td>
        <td>02/19/2002</td>
        <td>02/19/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WYYD</td>
        <td>02/11/2002</td>
        <td>02/11/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>

        <td>02/19/2002</td>

        <td>02/19/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>

        <td>02/19/2002</td>

        <td>02/19/2002</td>

        <td>Lockdown</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>05/19/2002</td>
        <td>05/19/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>

        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>
        <td>02/20/2002</td>
        <td>02/20/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WROC</td>
        <td>05/20/2002</td>
        <td>05/20/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WPPP</td>
        <td>02/19/2003</td>
        <td>02/19/2003</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WRRR</td>

        <td>02/19/2002</td>

        <td>02/19/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried anything or are you just looking for someone to do the work for you for free?

Comment: isn't that what stackoverflow is for?  free programming in exchange for internet points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting with this (untested). It should point you in the correct direction, all you need to do is include this after the table is created by deferring it or by calling initSelectableTable from the onload function. Make sure you set the id of your table to "SelectableTable".

```
var OldColour = "";
var SelectedRow = null;
var SelectedColour = "#DFDFDF";

initSelectableTable("SelectableTable");

function onCellClicked(cell) {
    if (cell.parentNode) {
        if (SelectedRow) SelectedRow.style.backgroundColor = OldColour;
        SelectedRow = cell.parentNode;
        OldColour = SelectedRow.style.backgroundColor;
        SelectedRow.style.backgroundColor = SelectedColour;     
    }
}

function initSelectableTable(tableid) {
    var elTable = document.getElementById(tableid);
    if (elTable) {
        var cells = elTable.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            cells[i].onclick = function () { onCellClicked(this); }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Looks promising, but "parentNode" is null or not an object (function onCellClicked(cell)

Comment: Let me stick it in a page and test it. I think you may have to define cells[i] before passing it to onCellClicked

Comment: @tunerscafe This is quite expensive, almost 300 eventhandlers and anonymous functions... :-(.

Comment: @Teemu - I agree and there are much better solutions out there which will take a lot more work and explanation, but this solution was intended to give a quick base for improvement.

Comment: @user1959234 colour was mis-spelled with the u and 'this' is now passed to the onCellClicked function.

Comment: @tunerscafe Please check my answer, a real code would have just few lines more...

Comment: @Teemu - I'd say it's roughly the same other than the multiple event handlers as you say. If you have the time, provide the code for the OP. I wanted to give him something quick and simple.

Comment: @Teemu - Looks good, you may need to address e.target for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tbody tr').bind('click', function (evn){
  $('tbody tr').css('background-color', 'white');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/raghu2314/RCEKW/1/

This will solve the problem, I've tested it working fine

Answer (score -2):

You can simply do that by the following code (Jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
  $('#mstrTable tr').not('thead tr').click(function () {
    $('#mstrTable tr').css('background-color', 'white');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#DFDFDF');             
  }); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/q42L2/3/)

**EDIT**

Excluded `thead` from the selection by using `Not`.

Comment: @authorOfThisQuestion "`id like to exempt that from ever changing color.`" this line has confused me. whether it is id or i would.?